# Unexpectedly truncated mediumtext field in MariaDB

Tags: php, mysqli, phpmyadmin, mariadb, contao

- System: GNU/Linux LMDE 2, Linux 3.16
- DB: MariaDB 10.0.30-MariaDB-0+deb8u1
- Server: Apache/2.4.10
- DB Interface Module: libmysql - 5.5.55
- PHP: PHP 5.6.30-0+deb8u1 with mysqli + mbstring module
- WCMS: Contao 3.0.5
- Browser: Opera 12

At reworking one of my websites with the WCMS Contao, I get a strange behaviour with longer texts in »text« and »accordion« elements. After 4448 chars or 4598 bytes, the text is truncated. The DB field »text« in table »tl_content« has the size »mediumtext«, which is 16MB in size. Repeated correcting the article in Contao doesn’t help.

Then I tried the same correcting directly with phpMyAdmin in the versions 4.8.0-dev, 4.7.0, 4.4.2 and 4.1.1, but there’s still no changing of the truncated text. Only in phpMyAdmin 4.4.2 there was an additional message »Oops, something went wrong!!«. No error no., no explanation, only that meaningless message!

Does anyone know, what’s going wrong when longer texts are truncated, and what’s the solution for solving this? Thanks a lot!

**Addendum 2017-08-22 16:00 GMT**

- MariaDB updated to 10.0.32-MariaDB-0+deb8u1
- DB Interface Module updated to 5.5.57
- another browser (Firefox 50.1.0) has the same problems
- textfield updating not from browser+phpMyAdmin but bash will do the job perfectly!

Therefore my conclusion: It seems that the disfunctional part can be one or more of the followings:

- browsers transmit per phpMyAdmin not enough data (unlikely)
- JavaScript interferes (unlikely)
- PHP interferes (unlikely)
- DB interface module can’t stand with MariaDB

**Addendum 2017-08-22 18:30 GMT**

- DB Interface Module libmariadb installed

Now I’m looking for the nessesary updates in /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini and/or other files. Any suggestions for the right places to edit to redirect the PHP MySQL functions to libmariadb?

Bert

Comment: When inserting utf8 strings, an invalid byte combination will cause truncation. Maybe you need to change your database charset to `utf8mb4`

Comment: Thanks, Hackerman! I switched to this charset and collate, but it doesn’t the job. :-(

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/charset-unicode-conversion.html

Comment: Look at where it was truncated.  What text should have been immediately after that point?

Comment: Rick: These tests I have already all behind me. There were no abnormalities.